# Designing a deterministic finite automata

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

How would I go about designing a deterministic finite automata to recognize the language

**L = {λ, ab, abab, ababab, . . . }**

consisting of strings that start with ‘a’, end with ‘b’, and alternate in between? Any help or push in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend CS.stackexchange.com for CS questions.  This is a fairly remedial regex / FSA question, do you know anything at all about the subject?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked “How would I go about designing…”.  You should imagine that someone has given you a very long string of symbols and asked *you* to verify this property.  The string is so long—perhaps thousands or millions of symbols—so that you cannot simply see it at a glance, as you can with short strings like `ababab`.  Then ask yourself what you could do to decide if the string has the required property.

Usually your idea will look something like this: “First I'll do (something), and then if I see an `a` I will do (something else), but if it's a `b` I will look at the next symbol, and then if it's an `a` I will do (some other thing).”  The decision points where you say “I look at the next symbol and if it's `a` I'll do (this) but if it's `b` I'll do (that)” are exactly the states of a finite automaton:

[image]

Here's an example which isn't the one from your question: Say I would like to check to see if a string contains two consecutive `a`s. How can I do this? I should  scan the string starting with the first character.  If I see an `a`, I will look to see if the next character is also `a`; if it is, the string has two consecutive `a`s, so I will accept.  If I see something else while looking for an `a`, I will continue scanning the string.  And once I have seen two `a`s, nothing else I see in the string will cause me to reject it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$q_0$- initial state

$q_1$-starts with 'a'

$q_2$-starts with 'ab', accepting state

$q_3$-starts with 'b'/'aa'

Now, note that if a word starts with 'ab' then it's legal iff the remainder of the word is legal, and once we found that a word is ruined somewhere then there is no redemption for this words.
Also, note that you can merge $q_0$, $q_2$

Now use those to obtain the complete automata.

Another and more advanced option is to build a regular expression that defines the language and use the algorithm that builds an dfa out of reg-exp